# Autolayout not pass to sublayer

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, calayer, cagradientlayer

I m using `Xamarin` for `iOS` v5.8.3(build 3).

I added a `UIView` with a `CAGradientLayer` on another `UIView` lie this:

```
public static void AddGradientView (CGColor color1, CGColor color2, UIView view) {
        UIView gradientView = new UIView (view.Bounds);
        gradientView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        gradientView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;

        CAGradientLayer gradient = new CAGradientLayer ();
        gradient.Frame = gradientView.Bounds;
        gradient.Colors = new CGColor[]{ color1, color2 };

        gradientView.Layer.InsertSublayer (gradient, 0);

        view.AddSubview (gradientView);
}
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

The problem is the gradient layer, His `frame` isn't fit to the wanted `UIView`.
I think it's an `Autolayout` issues.

Can anyone put me some light on it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S
The above code written in `objective sharpie` But it can be understood by an `iOS` developers easily ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CALayer and its subclasses are not affected by autolayout.

To update a layers frame you can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if you are updating a from a view controller, or `layoutSubviews` from a custom UIView subclass.

From a UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     // you need to store a reference to the gradient layer and gradient views or fetch them from the sublayers and subviews
     self.gradient.frame = self.gradientView.bounds;
}
```

UIView subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.gradient.frame = self.bounds;
}
```